# Change element position in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have a multidimensional array like this:

```
Array
(
    [Members] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => John
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [name] => Mark
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [name] => Paul
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => Robert
                )

        )

)
```

It's possible to change the position of name = Paul to the top of the array?

the output should be

```
Array
(
    [Members] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [name] => Paul
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => John
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [name] => Mark
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => Robert
                )

        )

)
```

Thank you!

Comment: no way i think so but why?

Comment: Yes.. swap value from top of the array to array value containing 'Paul'!

Comment: how? can you give me an example? please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could search for Paul first, then create a temporary holder for Paul, unset paul in the original array then unshift Paul inside it again so that he will come up top:

```
$array = [
    'Members' => [
        ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'John'],
        ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Mark'],
        ['id' => 4, 'name' => 'Paul'],
        ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Robert'],    
    ]
];

$name = 'Paul';
$temp = [];
foreach ($array['Members'] as $k => $value) {
    if($name == $value['name']) { // search for paul, if found
        $temp = $value; // put him inside temporarily
        unset($array['Members'][$k]); // remove paul
    }
}

array_unshift($array['Members'], $temp); // then put paul up top

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
```

[Simple output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/8vdtfx)